# Cycle through Gtk.EntryCompletion using Tab

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm trying to build an Gtk application in which the user has a search interface with auto complete feature. The user should be able to cycle through the results of the auto complete popup using TAB or arrow keys.

It seems like by default the Gtk.EntryCompletion implementation only allows cycling through results using the arrow keys. Is there any (easy) way to enable cycling through the results of the popup using the TAB key?

Here is a minimal example of Gtk's Entry Autocomplete feature:

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk

MOD_MASK = (Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK | Gdk.ModifierType.MOD1_MASK |
            Gdk.ModifierType.MOD4_MASK | Gdk.ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK)


class EntryCompletionExample:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.connect('destroy', lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        label = Gtk.Label('Type a, b or c. Use Arrow-Keys or Tab to cycle through items.')
        vbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

        # Init store
        store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        for item in ['apple', 'ananas', 'banana', 'orange']:
            store.append([item])

        # Configure completion
        completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
        completion.set_model(store)
        completion.set_text_column(0)

        entry = Gtk.Entry()
        entry.set_completion(completion)

        vbox.pack_start(entry, False, False, 0)
        window.add(vbox)
        window.show_all()
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ee = EntryCompletionExample()
    Gtk.main()
```